# Jquery Mobile, can i create a function that emulates a tap screen

Tags: jquery, events, mobile, tap

My Goal is to set a function that fires every 30 seconds that emulates a tap on the screen so that the screen stays on. Is this at all possible, or what is the best way to enable this without having to program it natively in Java.

I'll be happy if i can do it via phonegap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the Idle Timer if you're in PhoneGap, you'll need to add this to the UIApplication object.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled: YES];
```